# Load bitmap file (.bmp)

Tags: c++, bitmap, boost-gil

I noticed the boost::gil::extension::io only supports png or jpeg files.. While this is often enough I'm wondering how to load a bitmap (*.bmp) file into an image? Shouldn't this be actually easier than jpeg etc?

Comment: Interesting - it seems there was a support for BMP in GIL IO before it got accepted by BOOST: http://code.google.com/p/gil-contributions/source/browse/trunk/gil_2/boost/gil/extension/io/bmp_io.hpp?spec=svn70&r=70

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you solved it.
Just to add: install latest version of GIL on existing boost and then compile.
The bitmap files comes under new 'io_new' folder.

Comment: it is in branch develop but not in master yet https://github.com/boostorg/gil/tree/develop/include/boost/gil/extension/io